# Apache Access Log

Tags: apache-2.4, logging, log-files

I use fail2ban to detect malcious requests to any of my hosted domains, which is working very well, with one exception.

If a requests is sent to the IP instead of a fqdn or a subdomain, it gets catched and written into other_vhosts_access.log since the ip itself is no virtualhost.

Example entry:

> somedomain.de:80 20.37.96.167 - - [24/Jan/2020:15:47:04 +0100] "POST
>   //4walls/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1"
>   301 587 "https://www.google.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;
>   Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88
>   Safari/537.36"

So it seems, apache does a reverse lookup to the IP and writes down the hostname at first place.

This causes fail2ban to selfban the servers ip instead of the requesters IP.

How can i prevent the somedomain.de:80 entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> apache does a reverse lookup to the IP and writes down the hostname at first place.

If your filter made correctly (e. g. anchored regex without catch-all's) it does no matter where exactly the domain and foreign address are written.

I assume in your example log entry, the `somedomain.de` is yours and `20.37.96.167` is an address of "intruder".
Then the proper failregex would look like:

```
# ban everything (with code 300-599):
failregex = ^\S+\s+<ADDR>\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\[\]\s+"[^\"]+" [345]\d+
```

The anchored part `^\S+\s+<ADDR>` matches `somedomain.de:80 20.37.96.167` and would search in the string from begin only due to the anchor `^`.
This would be also enough as regex, if you have to ban everything from `other_vhosts_access.log` (regardless the resulting http-status).

If you have fail2ban version <= 0.9 use `<HOST>` instead of `<ADDR>`.

You could also check with `fail2ban-regex` whether it'd capture some false positives, for example:

```sh
fail2ban-regex --raw -vv /path/to/log '^\S+\s+<ADDR>\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\[\]\s+"[^\"]+" [345]\d+' \
  | grep <your-IP-or-hostname>
```

Comment: Yeah, this would have been a working solution, but my filter explicitly looked for 404 codes to detect exploit bruteforceing. I changed the default logformat from vhost_combined to combined and this fixed my issue